Use yum or versionlock to ignore packages associated with a repository
I have a RHEL-8 bash script that installs several packages including ansible. Some of the packages come from epel while others come from the default rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms. dnf-automatic has exposed a problem where ansible is available as both ansible-2.9.27-1.el8ae.noarch@ansible-2-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms and ansible-8.3.0-1.el8.noarch@epel with the following error(s):
systemctl status dnf-automatic.service
● dnf-automatic.service - dnf automatic
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnf-automatic.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-05-26 05:13:02 UTC; 2min 25s ago
  Process: 2758 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dnf-automatic /etc/dnf/automatic.conf --timer (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2758 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Last metadata expiration check: 0:55:41 ago on Sun 26 May 2024 04:17:17 AM UTC.
Error:
Problem: package ansible-8.3.0-1.el8.noarch from @System requires python3.11dist(ansible-core) >= 2.15.3, but none of the providers can be installed
 - cannot install both ansible-core-2.16.3-2.el8.x86_64 from rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms and ansible-core-2.15.3-1.el8.x86_64 from @System
 - cannot install both ansible-core-2.16.3-2.el8.x86_64 from rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms and ansible-core-2.15.3-1.el8.x86_64 from rhel-8-appstream-r>
 - cannot install the best update candidate for package ansible-core-2.15.3-1.el8.x86_64
 - problem with installed package ansible-8.3.0-1.el8.noarch
dnf-automatic.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dnf-automatic.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start dnf automatic.

Is there a way to make yum ignore the ansible package from epel repo and only install/update ansible from ansible-2-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms? This post seems really close but doesn't quite address the issue. This seems more like a yum versionlock issue but I haven't seen any documentation showing versionlock used to pin a repo. I also haven't had any luck with yum --enablerepo/disablerepo because even if it works initially, at some point there is an epel package that causes ansible (or one of ansible's dependencies) to get updated and I end up with both ansible 2.x and 8.x and the above mentioned error.

Have you try to set lower priority of epel repo?

No, I'm not familiar with setting priorities. Is that similar to yum-config-manager --setopt=epel.exclude=ansible --save? That seems to work but I'm not sure what downstream issues that may cause.
